# Flutter: The argument type 'Future<bool?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()?'

Tags: flutter, popup, exit, nullable

I create a `WillPopScope` Function for exit pop service. When user click on back button it's show a dialog for exit permission.

It worked on flutter version 1 perfectly. Now now for null issue, it's create a problem.

Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ExitPopUp extends StatelessWidget {
  final page;
  ExitPopUp(this.page);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<bool?> showExitPopUp() {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 68, 69, .5),
              title: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              content: Text("Do you want to Exit ?",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "No",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[100]),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, false);
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Yes",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[100])),
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    })
              ],
            );
          });
    }

    return WillPopScope(child: page, onWillPop: showExitPopUp);
  }
}
```

but here is a issue on onWillPop.

[image]

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You said it worked before the nullable change. What made you add the `?` in the line `Future<bool?> showExitPopUp() {`?

Comment: You may follow this SO post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297278/the-return-type-futurebool-function-isnt-a-futurebool-as-required-b

Comment: I add Future<bool?> for this time

Answer (score 0):

You can chnage your `WillPopScope` to this:

```
return WillPopScope(child: page, onWillPop: () => showExitPopUp().then(b -> b ?? false));
```

Or you can change your `showExitPopUp` from `Future<bool?>` to `Future<bool>`.

Comment: thanks. I just convert it to async function. and it's worked

Answer (score 0):

I just convert it to async function. And it's worked
here is updated code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ExitPopUp extends StatelessWidget {
  final page;
  ExitPopUp(this.page);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<bool> showExitPopUp() async {
      return await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 68, 69, .5),
              title: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              content: Text("Do you want to Exit ?",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "No",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[100]),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, false);
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Yes",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[100])),
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    })
              ],
            );
          });
    }

    return WillPopScope(child: page, onWillPop: showExitPopUp);
  }
}
```